# How to open file chooser from JSP page on click of a link?

Tags: javascript, html, jsp

I am working on a JSP page that allows user to upload an image file. This file will be later saved in database and will be used as their profile image. How can I open a file chooser dialog on click of a href link ?

I know about the `<input type = "file" />` solution but that is not part of the page design and I must open the file chooser from a href only.

Comment: it can be done through javascript , no direct ways

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this ,

```
<input type="file" id="upload" name="upload" style="visibility: hidden; width: 1px; height: 1px" multiple />
<a href="" onclick="document.getElementById('upload').click(); return false">Upload File</a>
```

See the working [**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/San_Krish/n1b7nmgx/)

And also can be done using CSS effect ,

[Read this link](http://www.quirksmode.org/dom/inputfile.html) for information

Answer (score 1):

### HTML

```
  <a href="#">
    Your Anchor tag
    </a>


    <input type="file" id="file"  />
```

### Jquery

```
$("a").trigger("click");

$(document).on("click", "a", function(){
    $('#file').click();
});
```

[**JSFIDDLE DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/sachindivakar/hnqL7nj6/1/)

Answer (score 1):

try this for open file chooser on click of href button,

```
<html>
<head>
<script>
function openDialog()
{
document.getElementById("file1").click();
}
</script>
</head>
<body>
<input type="file" id="file1" style="display:none">
<a href="#" onclick="openDialog();return;">open Dialog</a>
</body></html>
```